# Odd Exception when Combining .hbm.xml and Fluent NHibernate - Any ideas?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

So I'm converting my mapping files on an as needed basis (when making
changes, convert to mapping). Any when configuring NHibernate like so:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("RPMWare.Core.DataAccess");

//NHibernate configuration: see hibernate.cfg.xml
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.AddMappingsFromAssembly(asm);
cfg.Configure();
```

And running my web-application I get the following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.0.0.4000,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

However, all my integration tests are working as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. If you're using the latest version of Fluent NHibernate and the lastest version of NHibernate you need to add YOUR VERSION of NHibernate to the Fluent NHibernate project before building.

Comment: Yep. Run into that myself a few times.